# Use keys and pairing elements Perl

Tags: perl

My data looks like this:

```
    G1  G2  G3  G4
Pf1 NO  B1  NO  D1
Pf2 NO  NO  C1  D1
Pf3 A1  B1  NO  D1
Pf4 A1  NO  C1  D2
Pf5 A3  B2  C2  D3
Pf6 NO  B3  NO  D3
```

My purpose is to check in each column if an element (different from the "NO" cases) is showed twice (like A1 in column 2, for example) and only twice (if it is showed three times or more I don't want it in the output) and, if so, write the correspondent elements of the first column. So, the desired output looks like this:

```
Pf3 Pf4 A1
Pf1 Pf3 B1
Pf2 Pf4 C1
Pf5 Pf6 D3
```

I'm trying to write a perl script, but I need some help to focus on the different steps. This is what I did so far:

```
open (HAN, "< $file_in") || die "Impossible open the in_file";
@r = <HAN>;
close (HAN);
for ($i=0; $i<=$#r; $i++){
chomp ($r[$i]);
($Ids, @v) = split (/\t/, $r[$i]);
}
}
```

But I cannot go on in any direction!
(My perl knowledge needs to be pushed by you!)

The hot points in my mind are:

- how do I compare elements from the same column (or anyway in the same file)?
- how can I associate the elements of the first column with the other column ones (may be keys)?

Any help is absolutely necessary and welcome!

Comment: maybe yes, keys-values are good enough for your wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
while (<DATA>) {

    next if $.==1;
    chomp;
    my ($first,@others) = (split /\s+/);
    for (@others){
        $hash{$_}.=' '.$first;
    }
}

print Dumper \%hash;
__DATA__
    G1  G2  G3  G4
Pf1 NO  B1  NO  D1
Pf2 NO  NO  C1  D1
Pf3 A1  B1  NO  D1
Pf4 A1  NO  C1  D2
Pf5 A3  B2  C2  D3
Pf6 NO  B3  NO  D3
```

What I use here? (tricks)

`while (<DATA>){BLOCK}` - read data from specific DATA section in Perl script file. (yes, you can put test data here, if you want. But don't store everything! this is not a bin!)

`next if $.==1` - `$.` - special variable, that store a line number of input data. like 'index'.

`chomp;` - back to  `while(<DATA>)`.
Some variables in Perl are hidden. In functions - `@_` array of input parameters. And always Perl programmers like to use `$_` - `You` variable.

And this `while(<DATA>)` really a hidden `while(defined($_ = <DATA>))`.

Function `chomp` use `hidden-You` variable and try to chop \n symbol at the end.

Function `split /REGEX/` also take as default variable `hidden-You` variable (`$_`).

Comment: Thank you!! and thanks for tricks explanation...very illuminating!

Answer (score 1):

Perl multi liner :),

```
perl -anE '
  /^\S/ or next;
  $k = shift @F; 
  push @{$t{$_}}, $k for@F;
  }{ 
  @$_-1==2 and say join" ",@$_ for map [@{$t{$_}},$_], sort keys%t;
' file
```

Comment: @HunterMcMillen you're right, but at the beginning it seemed it should fit into "one line"

Comment: @mpapec good one, but can you add comments to your multi-liner? :) OP, I think, will be afraid of your magic ;)

Comment: @mpapec i'm trying your code also, but I get a syntax error about "say join"...don't know why!

Comment: @Gabelins you need at least perl `5.10` and run it from command line. I'll change code if you have older perl.